# How to get the latest updated data from firebase?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular5

[image: Firebase sample database image]

**how do i get the latest updated node from firebase** example in the above image link:

1. **DATA & SECOND_DATA** contains the **same nodes objects**. [have *multiple nodes* like these] around 8 nodes in the real-app.
2. **All** the **objects** can be **updated** i,e. `data1, data2, data3`. . . from both the nodes.
3. The object attributes are the same for all the nodes (name, password), only the value changes. **I need to get the latest node that is updated**. i,e. if `DATA.data3` is updated and then next `DATA.data2` is updated in firebase. how do i get the latest value for that particular DATA. That is `DATA.data1` and then next `DATA.data3`
4. The image is just a example. And the DB name is some-sample. In the real-app some-sample is also a node. I,e. some-sample is also a parent node, DATA and SECOND_DATA is a child node for some-sample.

> These value will be updated in Angularjs div every time firebase
>   latest data is updated. i,e if it will change in **DATA** the info
>   will be changed in *DATA div* if it changes in **SECOND_DATA** the
>   info in angular will be changed in *SECOND_DATA div*

FYI: I'm new to Firebase and Angular. Couldn't find these. An example would be really great thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase cloud functions can help you in this scenario.

You need to put a trigger on to the desired path where changes can occur.

```
export const onUpdate = functions.database.ref('some-samples/{firstId}/{secondId}').onUpdate(event => {
    let firstId = event.params.firstId;
    let secondId = event.params.secondId;
    let data = event.data.val();
    ...
});
```

You can perform some task here, which can be handled by server, instead of doing it on client end. Even if client is inactive task will be performed.

Answer (score 0):

in the latest version of the firebase(7.14.4) not need to use another method to get the latest updated data.

simply get the data from firebase through `snapshotChanges()` method

crud.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class CrudService {
    constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) { }
  
    //get data from firebase
    getFFList() {
      return this.firestore.collection('ff_list').snapshotChanges();
    }
 }
```

and get service data from component using

app.component.ts

```js
import { CrudService } from './services/crud.service';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  
  constructor(public crudService: CrudService) { }
  
  ngOnInit() {

    //get data
    this.crudService.getFFList().subscribe(data => {
      this.fflist = data.map(e => {
        return {
          id: e.payload.doc.id,
          ffdata: e.payload.doc.data(),
        };
      })
      console.log(this.fflist, "fflist");
    });

  }
  
}
```

your new updated data or newly added data display automatically in your HTML list. I hope this is helpful for you guys, thank you.